# Using 3D objects in an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, 3d, ipod-touch

How would I go about adding a 3D object from Maya into an iOS app? For now, before it gets too complicated, I just want to add it in, no response to touch yet. Is there a tutorial about this? Thanks!

Edit: It doesn't necessarily have to be Maya. I can learn how to use another program.

Comment: I would assume you're going to have to write your own rendering code. Maya is proprietary, and cocoa-touch doesn't include a library for any out of the box 3D rendering. OpenGL ES is available, but you would have to write your own rendering engine.

Comment: And I'm assuming that's really hard? Anyway, I was looking at the Elements app that Steve Jobs made a big deal about in the original iPad keynote, and wondered how they even put the objects in the app.

Comment: Are there rendering engines available for download, such as Cocos2D is for making games? Thanks!

Comment: Elements uses pre-rendered video, with time controlled by swipes left and right instead of a clock.  Elements does not use a 3d model.

Comment: @Alex Brown: do you have any more information about that? I tried to look at the .ipa of Elements to see what they used, and I see a bunch of .pv files. No idea what they are, videos or zip or 3D objects.

Comment: Take a look at the new iBooks building application in the mac application store - it provides this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Xcode and start an OpenGL-ES Project.

Export your maya-model to *.obj(Wavefront)-format and use [Jeff Lamarches obj-loader](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/wavefront-obj-loader-open-sourced-to.html) to create c-header files that you can include into your iPhone project!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a link to download the source code. Do you have one?

Comment: The link to the google-project page in the post is under "right here": http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/

Answer (score 9):

[Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) is a great open source iOS app that uses OpenGL ES to render 3D objects that have nice touch interaction. Maybe that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

For a more modern example of rendering 3D meshes, check out [this library](https://github.com/vovagalchenko/mishmesh). It comes with an OBJ parser, so if you can export your geometry as an OBJ file, you can render and interact with it using the library on iOS. Here's a [short video of the library in action](http://youtu.be/ahDldv0AnMc).